# Aiohttp websocket

Tags: websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to build a connection using AIOHTTP where from client-side I will get multiple requests continuously. So at the server-side, I have to create WebSocket connection using AIOHTTP so that I can accept multiple messages in a single stable connection while at the client-side I will create AIOHTTP to accept POST requests. I have surfed a lot but didn't get a proper code where I am accepting multiple messages over a single WebSocket connection using AIOHTTP. Can anyone help me with code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The flow you describe is not clear to me; do you need to have an aiohttp webapp that's also a websocket client to another upstream app?

Comment: I got a solution. Basically I just want to create a websocket connection using AIOHTTP

Comment: Should be fairly straightforward to use aiohttp's Websocket [client](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#websockets); [server](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#websockets) too.